# Does `string` in OCaml support UTF-8?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Does the type `string` in OCaml support `utf8`?

Or what library I should use for utf8 string?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `string` type of OCaml consists of a series of 8-bit bytes in essence. You can store a UTF-8 value in a string, and I have often done this. However, there's no built-in support for handling them. A good library for handling Unicode in OCaml (so I've heard) is [Camomile](http://camomile.sourceforge.net).

Comment: And if you're already using the Batteries Included libraries, there's the Rope data type which supports UTF-8: http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/doc.preview:batteries-beta1/html/api/Rope.html

Answer (score 3):

There is also [Uutf](http://erratique.ch/software/uutf/doc/Uutf) if you're looking for just unicode conversion.